# Creating grouped table view

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstableview, spotlight

Can anyone let me know what the procedure is to create the grouped `NSTableView` similar to the Spotlight results.

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for `NSOutlineView`-like collapse/expand functionality as well or just visual hints to indicate groups? If it's the latter then I suppose the question boils down to how to apply individual row spacings, right?

Comment: just the visual hint not collapse/expand.

Answer (score 4):

You probably won't get 100% there with the default behaviour provided by `NSTableView`, but pretty close.

For OS X v10.5 and up if you provide a `NSTableViewDelegate` ([NSTableViewDelegate Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSTableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSTableViewDelegate/tableView:isGroupRow:)) there's `tableView:isGroupRow:` you can provide.

Here's what it does for *Default* and *Source List* style table views on 10.6:
(setting the grouping flag for folders)

[image]

You can also provide `tableView:heightOfRow:` to adjust the row spacing and it get's pretty close (though with the group and content on different rows):

[image]

Other options that come to mind:

- provide a custom `NSCell` with image and text plus styling, or
- (for 10.7 and above) use an `NSView` based table view and an appropriate template

The **[TableViewPlayground](http://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/#samplecode/TableViewPlayground/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010727)** example might offer a good starting point for the latter.